# .join is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

Newer to coding and javascript and I am trying a codewars challenge.  I setup an array to repeat a letter at certain indexes of my `newArray` based on a loop.  For example if input was: `cwAt`   expected output should be: `C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt`.

Been stuck on this for several hours (and have slept on it).  I get error code:

> newArray.join is not a function

when I try to run this and not sure what I can do to fix this problem.  I feel its something simple and I just need to learn why this is happening.

```js
function accum(s) {
  let mumble = s.split('');
  for (i = 0; i < mumble.length; i++) {
    let newArray = [mumble[i].toUpperCase(), ''];
    for (j = i; j > 0; j--) {
      newArray = newArray.push(mumble[i]);
    };
    // Merge the new array into a string and set it at the mumble index required
    mumble[i] = newArray.join('');
  };
  //Return new mumble with - as spaces between elements
  return mumble.join('-');
}
console.log(accum('cwAt'));
```

Comment: This is a good time to encourage you to learn to use your debugger. Spotting that `newArray` was becoming a number wouldn't take long using a debugger.  It's an essential skill.

Comment: Why do you even need to assign `newArray` when you push into `newArray`. You are adding an item to `newArray` so there is no need to assign it to it self. and also as they said push return an interger of the index and not an array.

Comment: @Alen.Toma It's a common mistake.  Some array functions return a new array, and that expectation is mistakenly projected onto other functions.  I did the same thing starting out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `newArray = newArray.push(mumble[i]);` to `newArray.push(mumble[i]);`
push returns new length of the array.

Comment: It returns the new length of the array, which might be different from that position.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a number in `newArray`. Try replace the 4 line with:

```
let newArray[i] = [mumble[i].toUpperCase(), ''];
and the 5 line :
for (j = 0; j < 0; j++) {
and the 6:
newArray[j] = newArray.push(mumble[i]);
```

Comment: Punctuation is important in English, too. ;-)